# SSH rsa key works with external IP not internal IP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, public-key-encryption

I am using rackspace cloud hosting.  I have 2 servers behind a load balancer.  Each server has an external IP and an internal IP.  I want to setup a sync job that uses SSH to transfer files.  I made an rsa key, and I can successfully SSH from server A into server B, using the external IP of server B, without being prompted for a password.  If I try to do the same but use the internal IP, it prompts me for a password.  I want to be able to use the key instead of the password.  Why is this?  Is there something special I have to do during key generation so it works for both IPs?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you posted the commands you are using. You can supply ssh with a path to your keyfile: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa $IP`

Comment: My key file is in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys so I dont have to specify the key file.  So when doing this ssh username@externalIP it logs right in, when doing this ssh username@internalIP it prompts for a password.

Comment: `authorized_keys` are located on the server, you need to specify the private key you are using on the client. You can also create a `config` file in your `.ssh` folder. Check `man ssh_config` for syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add to the ~/.ssh/config file

```
Host internalIP
        IdentityFile ~/path/to/key
```